# How do I add a confirmation popup on a button (GET POST action in MVC)?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a get/post/JSON function on an aspx page.  This page adds data entered in a textbox to a table populated by javascript.  When the user select the submit button.  If the textbox is not empty, have a popup button telling the user the data in the textbox is not saved in the table. How do I have a confirm "ok/cancel" popup display on the post action in the Controller? 
I made a quick summary of what my code looks like.

```
...
<%  using (Html.BeginForm("AddName", "Name", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "AddNameForm" })) { %>
...
<table id="displayNameTable" width= "100%">                        
    <tr>
        <th colspan="3">Names Already Added</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="font-size:smaller;" class="name"></td>
    </tr>
</table>  
...
<input name="Name" id="txtInjuryName" type="text" value="<%=test.Name %>" />
...
<input type="submit" name="add" value="Add"/>
<% } %>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
           string confirmNext = "";
    if (test.Name == "")
    {
       confirmNext = "return confirm('It seems you have a name not added.\n\nAre Continue?')";
    }%>
    <input type="submit" name="getNext" value="Next" onclick="<%=confirmNext%>" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){ $("#form1").bind("submit", function(){ 
         if(!confirm('It seems you have a name not added.\n\nAre Continue?')) 
               return false;   
         });}          
     });

</script>
```

Comment: +1 for using jQuery to separate the client side interactions from the html element.  Helps maintainability.

Comment: THis is a good way to go... but how do I check to see if the textbox is empty or not???

Comment: add if($("#txtInjuryName").val()==""){...}

Comment: Thanks... I am new to the jquery usage.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the form's `onsubmit` event:

```
<form id="form1" onsubmit="return confirm('It seems you have a name not added.\n\nAre Continue?')">
    <input type="submit" name="getNext" value="Next" />
</form>
```

Also why `runat="server"` in an ASP.NET MVC application? Also you might consider specifying an `action` that this form is posting to and use the `Html.BeginForm` helper as for your first form.